# Javascript: remove a cookie that was set by an ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies

in my Webapp (that is running at `localhost/myApp/`), I have an ajax call like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/my.module/Login/login?user=abc&password=123",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true,
    },
    success: onResult,
    error: onError,
});
```

to login on the server. The server responds with a boolean value if the login was successful and the response also contains this header:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=167C57FA1E3529433938E744F7C4AC52; Path=/my.module
```

With the previously set xhrField "withCredentials: true", the browser automatically handles the cookie and appends the Cookie header in all following requests:

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=167C57FA1E3529433938E744F7C4AC52
```

This works perfectly fine. But now I have the problem, that the server has a bug so it doesn't remove a session when calling the logout interface, a session can't be closed (and I don't have access to the server). In order to logout properly I would have to remove the session cookie on the client so I would get a new one from the server. But i can't find a way to access or remove the cookie, the `document.cookie` variable is empty in my webapp. I also tried to read the `document.cookie` variable from `localhost/myApp/my.module/` and `localhost/my.module/`, but it is always empty. Another thing i tried was overwriting the cookie with

```
document.cookie = "JSESSIONID=ABC; Path=/my.module";
```

but the server requests still have the cookie from before. Can anyone tell me how i could remove it?

I know this solution would be a hack, but that's what I'm looking for, because the server programmers can't fix the bug in time and asked me to implement such a hack on the client.

Comment: That's probably an HTTP-only cookie! I think you have to remove it server-side

Comment: The cookie would be set on the server side.  If you can not remove it can you invalidate your session?

Comment: There is no `HttpOnly` Flag in the server response-header.

Comment: How could I invalidate my session? The logout interface should invalidate it, I think, but it doesn't (thats the bug on the server, and I have no possibility to fix it)

Comment: What I find weird is that you cannot touch the server, but what serves your JS then?

Comment: @Salketer - the app that runs the js can be part of a different application that uses the services that another application provides (server in this case).

Comment: @user1448982 You should reach out to the people who can change the server app. any other implemenation would be a hacky solution to the problem.

Comment: @ArvindSridharan yes, I am talking to the programmers of the server, they asked me to implement such a hack on the client, as they can't fix the problem on the server in time

Comment: Well, it might be very hacky, but what about sending another login request with invalid credentials? Does this remove the cookie?

Comment: @Jan no it doesn't. The only possibility to get a new Cookie would be to send a request without a Cookie to the server... Can I prevent the client from automatically appending the Cookie Header to my requests?

Answer (score 1):

"An HttpOnly cookie is not accessible via non-HTTP methods, such as calls via JavaScript " -http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Secure_and_HttpOnly

First of all, the client javascript shouldn't care about the cookie.
When the server sees a login request, it creates a new cookie and calls Set-Cookie.
On receiving any other ajax request, server validates the current cookie, before serving the request.
On logout request, it will clear the cookie from its (server's) session info i.e. any further requests from the client with the same cookie will fail since its not in the server store.

Comment: Yes, i know, but the programmers of the server asked me to remove the cookie on the client when logging out, because they have a bug on the server and can't fix it in time, so the server doesn't clear the cookie on logout. Thats why I'm asking this question here.

Comment: Then tell them to set an empty cookie on the response to ... let's say a logout action.